# Is it okay to answer old "fun" questions?

Tags: discussion, answers

There are a bunch of questions on this site which one might call "fun" questions: ones that ask for different ways of creating pretty pictures of a particular style in Mathematica. [You know the ones.](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/887/same-old-same-old)

Usually on StackExchange sites, there is no injunction against posting new answers to old questions, as long as your answer contributes something new. But in questions like these, there is no upper bound on the number of different possible answers, so there is a danger that new users might keep posting more and more answers to the question until the regulars get sick of seeing it on the front page again and again. Going by the linked thread, I'm worried that people might be tired of these kinds of questions already.

So, my question is: If I have a new and (in my opinion) interesting answer to an old fun-style question that hasn't seen any activity in months, should I post it, or should I leave well enough alone?

Comment: by all means, please post it. I always learn something new from interesting/different approaches. The answers that are really boring are those that say "I used X's answer with parameters Y and it looks cool to me"

Comment: Your answers are usually definitely worth adding, no matter how old the question. Besides, it's nice when these questions float to the top occasionally.